# Implementing "A2HS" feature on React App with Material-UI template

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, progressive-web-apps

Hello I’m trying to implement a “Add to home screen feature on my react app”.
The template that I’m currently using is from `Material-UI`. So I have created a component for the A2HS feature called `InstallPanel` with the event listeners and placed it inside the `home.js`. However the beforeinstallprompt wasn’t trigger and the button does not shows up.

home.js:

```
    <MenuIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title} noWrap>
        MOE MarketPlace
        <InstallPanel/>
      </Typography>
    </Toolbar>
```

InstallPanel.js:

```
    class InstallPanel extends React.Component {

      componentDidMount(){

        // Code to handle install prompt on desktop
        let deferredPrompt;
        const addBtn = document.querySelector('.add-button');
        addBtn.style.display = 'none';
        console.log('start')

        window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
          console.log('beforeInstall')
          // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
          e.preventDefault();
          // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
          deferredPrompt = e;
          // Update UI to notify the user they can add to home screen
          addBtn.style.display = 'block';

          addBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            console.log('clickEvent')
            // hide our user interface that shows our A2HS button
            addBtn.style.display = 'none';
            // Show the prompt
            deferredPrompt.prompt();
            // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
            deferredPrompt.userChoice.then((choiceResult) => {
                if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
                  console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt');
                } else {
                  console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt');
                }
                deferredPrompt = null;
              });
          });
        });
      }



      render() {

        return(
            <div className="container">

            <div>Hi there!</div>
            <button className="add-button">Add to home screen</button>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default InstallPanel;
```